# creating mount point in root mode

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, adb, mount

When trying to expand tablet memory (from 500 Mb to 1G) I made a mistake when I was applying Gparted. I reset my device to the fabrication settings and now I can't mount sd card (no the real sd card), so I can't transfer files between device and computer. Also, the date of some folders are too old(1969!) and some permission are weird:
[image]
How can I create a mount point? (I think this is the central problem to connect my device with PC).
I read somewhere that I must be root to change stuff in the tablet system, so I entered as root into the tablet with it:

```
adb shell
```

and I was prompted to

```
root@android:/ #
```

(now, am I in root mode, right?) and I can explore all the folders of my device. From this point, how can I create a mount point? what commands are required?. My tablet data are: SpreadwinPuppis model, Androdid 4.0.4, Core version 3.0.8+ spreadwin 2.4.10 (S101_SS_A), help :-/

Comment: after root@android need to type command su to be super user, then give commands like in mathcing linux system...